# View,Clicks and Wishlist for specific Product in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, products, product-collection, wishlist, products-view

I am working on website where i need to show unique `Views`,`Clicks`,`Wishlist` and `Overall views` of that product.For Unique Views i use this code :

```
$from = '2001-01-01';
        $to = now();
    $productIds = '2';
    $reports = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addViewsCount($from, $to)
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $productIds);
    $result = $reports->getData();

    return $result['0']['views']);
```

Now the problem is that the

1. `views = clicks ?` if not how can i get the clicks.
2. Above code is for
   unique views can i write custom code for overall views on product
   details page etc.
3. How can i get no of wishlist that have this
   product.I think collection with product filter can work.Do this is
   the right way ? Hope i can find any help for above any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Views - number of views the product at the catalog page, homepage slider, in related products block.

Clicks - number of product page open.

Do you think you can get this information from google analytics with some configured events?

Comment: Thanks for your message.How can i get the number of product page open.I didn't use Google analytics so i can either try custom code using events or write code on product page.Hope you got my point.